# Hide closest a element with a specific class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide an ahref element when a user clicks a button, i want it to delete the closes a tag with the class 'declineinvite'

Basically, I want it so when a user clicks the accept invite button, the accept button and decline button both fade out.

```html
<div class="user-list-slider owl-carousel  bottom-0">
  <div class="user-list-left">
    <img src="<?echo $theuser->photo;?>" alt="img" class="shadow-small bg-blue2-dark">
    <h4>
      <?echo $theuser->forename . " " . $theuser->surname;?>
    </h4>
    <p class="color-theme">
      Requested <?echo $date?>
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="next-slide-user bg-highlight">ACTIONS</a>
  </div>
  <div class="user-list-right">
    <h4>
      <?echo $theuser->forename . " " . $theuser->surname;?>
    </h4>
    <p class="color-theme">
      Requested <?echo $date?>
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="float-right icon icon-xxs icon-circle shadow-large bg-green2-dark left-5 sendinvite" request-id="<?echo$r->id;?>">
      <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="float-right icon icon-xxs icon-circle shadow-large bg-red2-dark left-5 declineinvite">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="<?echo base_url();?>user/<?echo $theuser->username;?>" class="float-right icon icon-xxs icon-circle shadow-large bg-highlight left-5">
      <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".sendinvite").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $(this).closest("declineinvite").hide();
  var requestid = $(this).attr("request-id");
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?echo base_url();?>",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      requestid: requestid
    },
    success: function(data) {}
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `closest()` method looks for the nearest *parent* element. The `.declineinvite` is a *sibling* of the clicked `.sendinvite`, so you can use either `next()` or `siblings()` instead.

Also note that if you want something to fade out, use `fadeOut()`. You can then, optionally, use the callback of `fadeOut()` to remove the element from the DOM completely:

```js
$(".sendinvite").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.next(".declineinvite").addBack().fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });

  // ajax request...
});
```